# CMS Rating system

Tags: support, site-recommendation

We are a small group of people drinking a specially brewed beer every week, and we need a rating system for them. Until now, we have been using a simple spreadsheet, but that's not user-friendly and hard to get online.

So, is there anyone who knows of a good system for what we want? Or maybe where to ask this question. I'm not sure MSO is the right place; if not, please do direct me in the right direction.

Any further questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Meta is not the proper place to ask this. Meta is specifically for asking questions about the Stack Overflow family of websites. For a CMS recommendation... I'm unsure if there is one among them which is best for your inquiry (closest I think is Super User but I'm not the most keen on their policies).

Comment: I'm adding that user picture to my 'adblock' list.

Comment: ccomet#
Okay, I will take a look there, I was also much in doubt myself.

George Stacker#
Thats fine I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suspected, this is not the right venue for your question.  Meta is for questions about StackOverflow, ServerFault and SuperUser.  Check out the [list of StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites); I know there's at least one brewing site.

Comment: And stackapps.com

Comment: Yes ... now er are getting somewhere. This was the best and only answer.